# Deleting last 10 characters of all txt file names in a directory (Python)

Tags: python, loops, filenames, file-rename, txt

Currently the file names in a directory are 'test1_1_4302929399.txt', 'test1_2_903929029.txt', 'test1_3_3949492929.txt' , how do I delete the last 10 digits in the file names for this directory so that the final is 'test1_1.txt', 'test1_2.txt', etc. **in python**? I have tried:

"""

```
import os

with open(filename, 'rb+') as filehandle:
    filehandle.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    filehandle.truncate()
```

"""

But this doesn't work for all files as they are named differently. Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to change the file name, why do you open the file

Comment: Oh good point! Is there a better way?

Comment: Try ```os.rename()``` - [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: I tried: import os

os.chdir(r'path')
print(os.getcwd())
COUNT = 1


# Function to increment count
# to make the files sorted.
def increment():
    global COUNT
    COUNT = COUNT + 1


for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_name = "Test1_ch3_" + str(COUNT)
    increment()

    new_name = '{} {}'.format(f_name, f_ext)
    os.rename(f, new_name)                               But the issue is, how do I know that the count is indeed the correct number for the original sensor file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `os.rename`

```
import os
path1=....
for i in os.listdir(path1):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path1, i),os.path.join(path1, i[:8])+'.txt')
```

Comment: Hi @Sujay! Currently the file changes to type '.file' instead of '.txt' because this trims the extension. Do you know how I can keep the file type as '.txt'?

Comment: ```os.path.join(path1, i[:8])+'.txt'``` @sarah Try to substitute this

Comment: @sarah consider accepting and upvoting the answer

Comment: I tried giving upvoting but I only have '11 reputation' points, and apparently we need 15 to upvote. Is there another way?

Comment: @sarah No problem, you can upvote later if you want, currently, you can mark the answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the glob module to iterate over different files, and use the * wildcard to substitute for the last 10 characters.

```
from glob import glob
import os

for file_name in glob(directory + "/test_*.txt"):   # Directory specifies path to the file if needed
    base = os.path.basename(file_name) # returns test_*.txt for each file
    os.rename(file_name, directory + base[:7] + '.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of all filenames, then split them on the '_' character and join the first two parts back to a string, adding the .txt back after.

```py
import os

file_names = ["test1_1_4302929399.txt", "test1_2_903929029.txt", "test1_3_3949492929.txt"]

for filename in file_names:
    os.rename(filename, '_'.join(f.split('_')[0:2]+'.txt'))
```

The signature for the `os.rename()` function is:

```
os.rename(src, dest)
src: path to source file or directory to rename
dest: path to destination path or directory (new)
```

Note if the destination already exists you will get a OSError

---

If a list of files is not appropriate then one can use listdir from the os module:

```py
import os

path_to_files = './files'

for file in os.listdir(path_to_files):
    os.rename(file, '_'.join(file.split('_')[0:2]+'.txt'))
```

The use of split on '_' becomes useful in this case since the numbers x and y in testx_y become longer than one character.

Comment: Thanks! The only issue is that I don't know the exact last 10 digits for all the files. They are automatically created and there are about ~350 of these such files so creating a list of the names might be difficult. But many thanks!! Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Sure, in that case using something like `for i in os.listdir(path_to_dir)` like in Sujay's answer would be appropriate.